# Setting Data Annotation min property message with value from another property?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I have a List of objects in my View Model (C# MVC4).
The object is like this:

```
public int IdContainer { get; set; }
public string DisplayName { get; set; }
[Min(1, ErrorMessage = "The Quantity must be greather than 0.")]
public int Quantity { get; set; }
```

The problem is that i'm showing the list of the error messages in a list, so if i have more than one object in the list and both objects have the Quantity in 0 i have two equal error messages like this:

```
The Quantity must be greather than 0.
The Quantity must be greather than 0.
```

Can i do something to difference this messages by modifying the ErrorMessage and put the DisplayName property inside the message?